# Return value of scala.util.Try block

Tags: scala

I have a question about the Example in scala.util.Try API.
[The code example](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/util/Try.html)

```
...
```

case Success(v) =>
…
Success(v) // That's clear the return value is Success(value)
case Failure(e) =>
…
divide

```
// Input any non-parsable Int should return an Failure(e) instance, right?
// Why is the return value divide, the method itself?
// What does returning divide mean?
```

Comment: That is because that function is recursive, always waiting for the input of the user, so when the function fails, it simply says the you messed up and to try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has called the divide function again like recursion. It keeps calling itself until there is a success.

For example when you run it in repl,

```
scala> divide
Enter an Int that you'd like to divide:
Enter an Int that you'd like to divide by:
You must've divided by zero or entered something that's not an Int. Try again!
Info from the exception: / by zero
Enter an Int that you'd like to divide:
```

I have passed denominator value zero so it has called divide function again.

Hope, it will help.